# APP_INITIALIZER raises "Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef_" when used with a custom Http provider that is redirecting

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dependency-injection

I am using a custom Http provider to handle API authentication error. In my CustomHttp, I need to redirect the user to the login page when a 401 status error is emitted by the API. That works fine!

app.module.ts

```
export function loadCustomHttp(backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: AppRequestOptions,
  router: Router, dataHelper: DataHelperService) {
  return new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, router, dataHelper);
}

@NgModule({
// some declarations, imports, ...
providers: [
// some services ...
 {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: loadCustomHttp,
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, Router, DataHelperService] 
    }
});
```

custom-http.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, ConnectionBackend, Request, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { DataHelperService } from '../helpers/data-helper.service';
import { AuthStorage } from '../services/auth/auth-storage';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
    private router: Router, private dataHelper: DataHelperService) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }


  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.intercept(super.request(url, options));
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.intercept(super.get(url, options));
  }

  post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.intercept(super.post(url, body, options));
  }

  put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.intercept(super.put(url, body, options));
  }

  delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.intercept(super.delete(url, options));
  }



  intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
    return observable.catch((err, source) => {
      let token = AuthStorage.getToken();

      if (err.status === 401 && token && AuthStorage.isTokenExpired())    { 
        // token has expired -> redirecting user to login
        AuthStorage.clearAll();
        this.router.navigate(['auth/login']);
      }
      return Observable.throw(err);
    });
  }
}
```

Then, I tried to use the `APP_INITIALIZER` opaque token to get the required settings to initialize my app.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
// some declarations, imports, ...
providers: [
// some services ...
    ConfigService,
    { 
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => () => config.load(), 
      deps:[ConfigService, Http],
      multi: true
    }
});
```

config.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AppSettings } from '../../environments/app-settings';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

  public settings:AppSettings;

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  load() : Promise<AppSettings> {
    let url = '/settings/';

    var observable= this.http.get(url)
            .map(res => res.json());

    observable.subscribe(config => this.settings = config);
    return observable.toPromise();
  }

}
```

This creates an error :

```
Uncaught Error: Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef_: in NgModule AppModuleNgModuleProviderAnalyzer.parse @ provider_analyzer.js:291NgModuleCompiler.compile @ ng_module_compiler.js:54RuntimeCompiler._compileModule @ runtime_compiler.js:102RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ runtime_compiler.js:65RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ runtime_compiler.js:55PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ application_ref.js:303PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ application_ref.js:285(anonymous function) @ main.ts:18__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0e2b412…:52(anonymous function) @ main.bundle.js:86665__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 0e2b412…:52webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 0e2b412…:23(anonymous function) @ main.bundle.js:1
```

If I comment out the custom Http provider, the error is not shown and the `APP_INITIALIZER` works as expected.
If I remove the `Router` from the Http provider deps declaration, I don't have the error anymore but the my `ConfigService.load()` function is called twice.

Does anyone knows why this router dependency is causing this cyclic dependency error ?
How can I prevent my `ConfigService.load()` function to be called twice ?

If needed, I have created a public repository reproducing the error : https://github.com/haia212/AngularErrorTestProject

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The problem is that `Router` can async load some routes. This is why it needs `Http`. Your `Http` depends on `Router` and `Router` depends on `Http`. Angular injector is not able to create any of these services.

I had similar problems and one of the solutions can be injecting `Injector` instead of service and getting service afterwards.

Code:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions,
    private injector: Injector, private dataHelper: DataHelperService) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  public get router(): Router { //this creates router property on your service.
     return this.injector.get(Router);
  }
  ...
```

So, basically, you do not need `Router` to get instance of `Http` service. The injection is done when you access `router` property - only when you want to redirect user. `router` property is transparent to other parts of code.

If it will not solve problem, you can do the same thing to the rest of injected services (except these to call `super`).

Comment: Be advised, that injecting the injector is considered a bad practice, because it makes your class tightly coupled with specific DI implementation and it defeats the purpose of DI in the first place.

Comment: @SlavaFominII Sure thing. Injecting `Injector` isn't good practice and is often a sign of bad design (example: two services depends on each other mean that purpose of these services is not defined correctly). In this case however, I do not see any way to preserve perfect design without limiting functionality. Locking to specific DI implementation seems to not be a big issue here (virtual problem, I must say), as you are locked to Angular anyway. Also, `Injector` is an abstract class, so you can provide your implementation if needed.

Comment: Brilliant!! How could you find out the problem from injecting Router service? I faced the same issue and I cannot find out why. Thanks for that!

Comment: This makes the code compile but you still get the Circular dependency as a warning.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it simply by removing Router from the `deps` declarations :

```
{
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: loadCustomHttp,
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, DataHelperService]
    }
```

And everything else stay the same.
It feels a bit like magic but it works.

Comment: If Router wasn't needed in the first place when loading another provider, then removing Router from 'deps' parameter as you did resolves the cyclic dependency error, but all this doesn't speak to the scenario where you actually have an actual cyclic dependency (i.e. A depends on B and B depends on A).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps; the way I solved this is by changing the strategy for the  `CustomHttp` class to use composition instead.

My `CustomHttp` looks something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp {

    constructor(private http: Http) {}
```

Now, I don't need Router nor any other service injected in my custom Http service.

In the configuration loader (`config.service.ts`) I made the following changes:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { AppSettings } from '../../environments/app-settings';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {

  public settings:AppSettings;

  constructor() { }

  load(http: Http) : Promise<AppSettings> {
    let url = '/settings/';

    var observable= http.get(url)
            .map(res => res.json());

    observable.subscribe(config => this.settings = config);
    return observable.toPromise();
  }

}
```

Removed the need to inject the `Http` service dependency and instead added it to the `load(http: Http)` method.

In my `app.module.ts` I have the following:

```
providers: [
    {
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: (backend, options) => new CustomHttp(new Http(backend, options)),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    },
    ConfigService,
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: (config, http) => () => config.load(http),
        deps: [ConfigService, Http],
        multi: true
    },
```

This is what I am currently using on my app. Not sure if this approach will work for you but hope it helps.