# Angular 5 set routes from API with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-universal

I'm using [Angular Universal Starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) for my application and I try to build a dynamic routing system from an API.
I would like to configure my routing system before the application bootsrap. To do this, I used the [APP_INITIALISER](https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER). I followed different way, especially this one : [Angular 5 Build routes from API data at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953281/angular-5-build-routes-from-api-data-at-startup)

My problem come on my app.module.ts file :

```
export function initRoutes(routes: RouterService) {
    return () => routes.browse();
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule.withServerTransition({appId: 'universal'}),
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([]),
        TransferHttpCacheModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        InjectorModule,
        HomeModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        HomeComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        NetworkService,
        RouterService,
        {
            'provide': APP_INITIALIZER,
            'useFactory': initRoutes,
            'deps': [ RouterService ],
            'multi': true,
        },
        Title,
        MenuService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

When I import `TransferHttpCacheModule` (an interceptor that avoids duplicate HttpClient requests on the client, for requests that were already made when the application was rendered on the server side), I'm getting the following error :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBam9.jpg)

My question is : Is it possible to send a JSON (with a routes list) to configure my routing system on an SSR application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array like this:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'aRoute',
    component: NameComponent
  },
  ...
]
```

and in the NgModule imports add this:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
```

then if you go to the path `aRoute`, NameComponent will be rendered.

Comment: Yes but I would like to load the routes list dynimacally from a service before the application bootstrap (idealy on the server). The routes list is build from an API (administrated with a CMS)

Comment: Possible your problem is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39767019/app-initializer-raises-cannot-instantiate-cyclic-dependency-applicationref-w)

Comment: Not really. My problem come from the import of TransferHttpCacheModule (define for angular Universal) with the use of APP_INITIALIZER

Comment: If you unimport this the problem is gone? I tried to reproduce your problem but was impossible for me, can you create a plunkr?

Comment: Yes, if I unimport this the problem is gone. But I need it to avoid duplicate HttpClient requests

Comment: Look at [this](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/901), It suggest use Injector for the HttpClient in the APP_INITIALIZER `get http() { return this.injector.get(HttpClient); }`, hope it helps!